# Active Admin dropdown not showing rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a simple app with loads modal i had added Active Admin gem and it worked perfectly but when i tried to edit a load from Active Admin UI but it doesn't shows drop down form some of my fields:[image: this is what i got instead of drop down]

**My load form**

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :name, label: "Tittle", placeholder: 'Give A Tittle To Your Shipment' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :description, label: "Description", placeholder: 'Define Your Shipment' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pickup">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="field">
      <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
      <%= f.input :from, :collection => ["Kolkata"],
:input_html => {:class => 'selectpicker'}, :label => 'Pickup (City)', :prompt => 'Select Pickup City' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="delivery">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="field">
      <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
      <%= f.input :to, :collection => ["Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Delhi"],
:input_html => {:class => 'selectpicker'}, :label => 'Delivery (City)', :prompt => 'Select Delivery City' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**admin_user.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**shipment model**

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PublicActivity::Model
    tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :delete_all
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300#" }, :default_url => "missing.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**active modal shipment model**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Shipment do

# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
#
 permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model, :name, :description, :from, :to, :date, :pay, :status, :image
#
# or
#
# permit_params do
#   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
#   permitted << :other if resource.something?
#   permitted
# end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveAdmin ForbiddenAttributesError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655366/activeadmin-forbiddenattributeserror)

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Is there an error (as the heading suggests), or is your app simply not behaving the way you expected (as your post suggests)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add :as=> select
example code is given below:

```
f.input :from, :as => :select, :collection => ["Kolkata","Mumbai"]
```

Comment: did that @kajal but that doesn't helped

Comment: @ShadabAlam Can you please provide the complete code of the active admin model in which you are writing this code

Comment: added the active admin model

Comment: I meant to say your shipment model